# identifiers in visual basic form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a form, user logs in and another form is generated.

User submits a query. My problem is that I cannot keep a record of who is making the query.

The user has a uid and usernamae but once the new form is generated where the user submits the query both these identifiers are gone.

Is there a way in which I can overcome this? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean, "they are gone"?  Out of scope?

Comment: I mean that in my code for the second form its a new class and I dont know how to find them? is there a way i can still use the username or uid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're storing your UIDs *only* in the initial form, you'll need to pass in these values to the new form.

In essence, you could adjust your fields scopes and store your value in a place accessible by both forms, pass them into a constructor (and store accordingly), or provide an accessor in your new form to pass through the values you need.

To answer your question on the constructor:

Your code currently probably looks like the following:

```
Dim form2 as New Form2()
form2.Show()
```

You'll need to modify the constructor of the second form such as:

```
Public Sub New() ...
```

...should become...

```
Public Sub New(ByVal userId As String, ByVal userName As String) ...
```

And then pass in your values from the first form (where userId and userName are fields storing form1's values):

```
Dim form2 as New Form2(userId, userName)
form2.Show()
```

Then you could store them in your second form's global scope.

Comment: stupid question but how can I pass them into a constructor? are there any links or tutorials on how to do this? Thanks

Comment: @user765942 See update.  Apoliogize for any keyword ommissions, as VB.NET isn't my primary language.

Comment: Thanks George, I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

This is how I brought across the value into a new form. Seems like an easy fix, didnt realise it was so straightforward!

Dim val As String = CStr(Form1.ComboBox1.SelectedValue)